# Can't stop Observable interval

Tags: angular, rxjs, intervals

I have tried just about everything I can find and can't seem to get this interval to stop doing the code inside the subscribe. Am I using the interval wrong?

```
var subject = new Subject();
var interval = Observable.interval(this.settings.timing * 1000);
var subscription = interval
  .takeUntil(subject)
  .subscribe(t => {
  console.log('pushing new item');
  this.activeItems[0].contentLeaving = true;
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.activeItems[0].imageLeaving = true;
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.activeItems.push(this.activeItems.shift());
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.activeItems[1].contentLeaving = false;
        this.activeItems[1].imageLeaving = false;
      },510);
    },510);
  },510);
});
this.moduleProps.intervals.push(subject);
```

In my `ngOnDestroy`

```
this.moduleProps.intervals.forEach((i)=>{
  i.complete();
});
```

But after this happens I still see the console log statement saying "pushing new item" as if it's still running on my interval.

Comment: You can call `subscription.unsubcscribe()` inside `subscribe()`. Or maybe I don't understand what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

As per this documentation (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html), takeUntil emits until the provided observable emits. You are completing the observable without emitting anything. Try adding .next() to your onDestroy method.

```
this.moduleProps.intervals.forEach((i)=>{
  i.next(); // have subject emit
  i.complete();
});
```

Here is a working plunk (https://plnkr.co/edit/Zdf8C9d8vHk84uIMYHvH?p=preview)

Comment: I have tried that as well, also have `.next()` pass something back and the interval keeps going.

Comment: @Jordan, can you just store your interval subscription(s), then in your ngOnDestroy unsubscribe from those to stop the interval. Instead of using the takeUntil operator

Comment: I've tried that as well, it doesn't work either. Interestingly, if I try to call `.next()` and `.compelte()` immediately after I set them up within a timeout, it all works perfectly. It's only not working when I try to use the reference later one

Comment: @Jordan Are you sure the ngOnDestroy method is being fired?

Answer (score 0):

Try `.takeWhile` instead of `.takeUntil`, it can use a boolean.

```
private finished = false;  // component property

var interval = Observable.interval(this.settings.timing * 1000);
var subscription = interval
  .takeWhile(_ => this.finished)
  .subscribe(t => {
  ...
```

OnDestroy is then simply `this.finished = true;`

Comment: takeWhile takes in a function that is suppose to return a boolean, not just a boolean